# adapt multiprocessing Pool to mpi4py

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mpi4py

I'm using multiprocessing Pool to run a parallelized simulation in Python and it works well in a computer with multiple cores. Now I want to execute the program on a cluster using several nodes. I suppose multiprocessing cannot apply on distributed memory. But mpi4py seems a good option. So what is the simplest mpi4py equivalence to these codes:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(processes=16)

pool.map(functionName,parameters_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

There's an old package of mine that is built on `mpi4py` which enables a functional parallel map for `MPI` jobs.  It's not built for speed -- it was built to enable a`MPI` parallel map from the interpreter onto a compute cluster (i.e. without the need to run from the `mpiexec` from the command line).  Essentially:

```
>>> from pyina.launchers import MpiPool, MpiScatter
>>> pool = MpiPool()
>>> jobs = MpiScatter()
>>> def squared(x):
...   return x**2
... 
>>> pool.map(squared, range(4))
[0, 1, 4, 9]
>>> jobs.map(sqaured, range(4))
[0, 1, 4, 9]
```

Showing off the "worker pool" strategy and the "scatter-gather" strategy of distributing jobs to the workers. Of course, I wouldn't use it for such a small job like `squared` because the overhead of spawning the `MPI` world is really quite high (much higher than setting up a `multiprocessing` `Pool`).  However, if you have a big job to run, like you would normally run on a cluster using `MPI`, then `pyina` can be a big benefit for you.

However, the real advantage of using `pyina` is that it can not only spawn jobs with `MPI`, but it can spawn jobs to a scheduler.  `pyina` understands and abstracts the launch syntax for several schedulers.

A typical call to a `pyina` map using a scheduler goes like this:

```
>>> # instantiate and configure a scheduler
>>> from pyina.schedulers import Torque
>>> config = {'nodes'='32:ppn=4', 'queue':'dedicated', 'timelimit':'11:59'}
>>> torque = Torque(**config)
>>> 
>>> # instantiate and configure a worker pool
>>> from pyina.launchers import Mpi
>>> pool = Mpi(scheduler=torque)
>>>
>>> # do a blocking map on the chosen function
>>> pool.map(pow, [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])
[1, 64, 2187, 65536]
```

Several common configurations are available as pre-configured maps.
The following is identical to the above example:

```
>>> # instantiate and configure a pre-configured worker pool
>>> from pyina.launchers import TorqueMpiPool
>>> config = {'nodes'='32:ppn=4', 'queue':'dedicated', 'timelimit':'11:59'}
>>> pool = TorqueMpiPool(**config)
>>>
>>> # do a blocking map on the chosen function
>>> pool.map(pow, [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])
[1, 64, 2187, 65536]
```

`pyina` needs some TLC, in that it's still `python2.7` and that it hasn't had a release in several years… but it's been kept up to date (on github) otherwise and is able to "get the job done" for me running jobs on large-scale computing clusters over the past 10 years -- especially when coupled with `pathos` (which provides `ssh` tunneling and a unified interface for `multiprocessing` and `ParallelPython` maps).  `pyina` doesn't yet utilize shared memory, but does do embarrassingly functional parallel computing pretty well.  The interactions with the scheduler are pretty good in general, but can be a bit rough around the edges for several failure cases -- and the non-blocking maps need a lot of work.  That having been said, it provides a pretty useful interface to run embarrassingly parallel jobs on a cluster with `MPI`.

Get `pyina` (and `pathos`) here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Answer (score 4):

There is an `MPIPool` class implemented [here](https://github.com/dfm/mpipool/).

For an example of how I use this, check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/adrn/33bec127338b9774d0f8) on GitHub.

Comment: Can you include a summary of how to use it, or a short example in your answer as well? From the Help Center [How to Write a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to be equivalent to multiprocessing.Pool. It has not yet been tested extensively, but it seems to work just fine:

```
from functools import partial
function = partial(...)  # Store all fixed parameters this way if needed

if use_MPI:
    arguments = range(num_runs)
    run_data = None

    # mpi4py
    comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable, args=['MPI_slave.py'], maxprocs=num_runs)  # Init
    comm.bcast(function, root=MPI.ROOT)     # Equal for all processes
    comm.scatter(arguments, root=MPI.ROOT)  # Different for each process
    comm.Barrier()                          # Wait for everything to finish...
    run_data = comm.gather(run_data, root=MPI.ROOT)  # And gather everything up
else:        
    # multiprocessing
    p = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    run_data = p.map(function, range(num_runs))
```

This then uses a separate file 'MPI_slave.py':

```
from mpi4py import MPI
# import the function you actually pass to this file here!!!
comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Get_parent()
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

def runSlaveRun():
    function = None
    options = None
    # print("Process {}/{} reporting for duty!".format(rank, size))

    function = comm.bcast(function, root=0)
    arguments = comm.scatter(options, root=0)
    results = function(arguments)
    comm.Barrier()
    comm.gather(results, root=0)
    comm.Disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runSlaveRun()
```